# Customize Exception Message for a Integer convertion - Ruby

Tags: ruby, exception, error-handling

I am trying to do a safe_Int(n).

If the input is not an "integerble" value (ex: 123 or '123') it should return a TypeError and the message: "#{n} must be a number".

Here is what I did:

```
def safe_Int(n)
 begin
  Integer(n) rescue TypeError
 rescue TypeError => e
  puts "#{n} is not a number" 
 end 
end
```

I am not able to display the message that I want.

I am getting "no implicit conversion of Class into Integer"

How can I customize the error message?

Comment: This is probably a bad idea. `.to_i` is the safe way to convert, it works on pretty much anything that can coerce itself into an integer. Hard-casting like that is a pretty heavy-handed approach. Likewise, converting exceptions to random output isn't really helpful, that just ignores what could be serious problems.

Comment: .to_i is not good for my needs... I also need to get the same message for boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Ok! Found what I was looking for:

```
def safe_Int(n)
Integer(n)
rescue
  raise TypeError.new "#{n} is not a number!"
end
```

obs: I am not showing the full code, so I will not be the spoiler for the challenge.

Comment: This really flouts a lot of Ruby conventions, method names should be all-lowercase, but all you need to do if that's your goal is: `raise TypeError, "..."` where `new` is not explicitly necessary. The second argument is forwarded to the constructor for you automatically.

Comment: well done!! Thank you for spotting this! I will pay more attention and keep all-lowercase! Tnks!

Answer (score 0):

Not saying that I think this is a good idea, but `Integer(n)` raises an `ArgumentError` not a `TypeError` so your code should be something like:

```
def safe_int(n)
  Integer(n)
rescue ArgumentError => e
  puts "#{n} is not a number"
end
```

Comment: you may be right or not :D.. this was one discussion that Matz had [link](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/2830) is TypeError a subclass of ArgumentError? but I really need it as TypeError, displaying that message...

Comment: All I know is that `Integer('a')` gives me an `ArgumentError` :) Your code was a bit confusing can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: of course it is confusing! I am learning! LOL!! :D
I am trying to make a challenge at codewars.com. I figured out how to do it... and after I saw the "best practice" solution!! Hey it was REALLY easy!
`Integer(n)
rescue
  raise TypeError.new "#{n} is invalid"`